# Where can I find an ontology for “project”?

Tags: data-request, metadata, ontology

I am looking for an ontology that can describe the concept "project". For example:

- the type of the project (new project, improvement, translate)
- industries involved in the project (mobile application, design, music)
- products of the project

but I can't even find a keyword for such a case.

Are there any suitable ontologies for my case?

Answer (score 4):

DOAP - Description of a Project. still alive, now on github
https://github.com/edumbill/doap/wiki

Comment: [Linked Open Vocabularies](http://lov.okfn.org/) also suggests [DOAP for "project"](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/search?q=project) and provides [additional information](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/details/vocabulary_doap.html).

Answer (score 2):

A list of ontologies used in Linked Open Data using project can be found here https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=project